# does .NET 4.0 client profile support all the features of google calendar API V3?

Tags: c#, .net, google-calendar-api

error: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks, Version=2.5.19.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies

I'm using Google calendar API V3 for .net and am running into an issue where the application cannot find the reference to System.Threading.Tasks. this happens on my development server where I have deployed it and on my local system I do not face any issue and it works fine.

what I've tried to resolve this issue and didn't work.
[reference][1]

1. updated Microsoft.Bcl.Async from nuget
2. manually redirected assembly in config file

   ```
   <assemblyIdentity name="System.Threading.Tasks" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
       <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.5.19.0" newVersion="2.5.19.0" />
   ```

I have .net 4.0 full version on my local setup while 4.0 client profile we remote server
So my question is I'm getting this error due to 4.0 client profile?
and what am I missing to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue, it was due to the different version of System.Threading.Tasks provided google api client and the one present with .Net 4.0 framework. I got .Net framework re-installed since the dll were not properly updated and then added the binding to reference the latest System.Threading.Tasks dll.

Answer (score 0):

`Microsoft.Bcl.Async` is for projects that can't use .NET 4. Since .NET 4, the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace is in mscorlib.dll, so it is available even with the Client Profile.

Simply remove the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package from your project as well as the `bindingRedirect` in your config and you should be good to go.

Comment: Daniel,Initially I tried what you suggested but it didn't work. since google calendar API rfers system.threading.task internally and I've not referred to the assembly explicitly.